# process second column if first column matches

Tags: bash, awk

I just want the second column to be multiplied by exp(3) if the first column matches the parameter I define.

cat inputfile.i

```
100 2
200 3
300 1


100 5
200 2
300 3
```

I want the output to be:

```
100 2
200 60.25
300 1

100 5
200 40.17
300 3
```

I tried this code:

```
awk ' $1 == "200" {print $2*exp(3)}'  inputfile
```

but nothing actually shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not printing the unmatched lines, you don't need to quote numbers

```
$ awk '$1==200{$2*=exp(3)}1' file

100 2
200 60.2566
300 1


100 5
200 40.1711
300 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a difference between inputfile.i and inputfile?

Anyway, here is my solution for you:

```
awk '$1 == 200 {printf "%s %.2f\n",$1,$2*exp(3)};$1 != 200 {print $0}'  inputfile.i
100 2
200 60.26
300 1


100 5
200 40.17
300 3
```